# How do i stop blocking read on BufferedReader.readline()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small program whereby in the main thread, I ask for input from the user in the console.

```
System.out.print("Alternatively, enter peer's ID to connect:");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
String peerID = bReader.readLine();
```

and in a separate thread I listen from my sockets' InputStream. If I receive something from this stream, i then try to "unblock" the readLine by calling `System.in.close()` without waiting for the user's input. The main thread can then proceed to do something with the information obtained either from the socket's read or from the user.

Somehow it seem to work on my Mac, but if I try it on Windows, stepping through the debugger, I've found that `System.in.close()` blocks and the whole program will hangs.

Any idea why and how should i unblock `readline()`? Otherwise what would be a good way of rewriting the logic?

Comment: Have you had experience with these solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6008607/365237 http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456207/365237

Answer (score 1):

You could try to close `bReader` instead, but a sounder approach would be to use interruptible io in the nio package and possibly the `Console`. I would try using the [Console.read(CharBuffer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29), and interrupt the thread. That "should" work. Haven't tested though...

**Update:** But a [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) would maybe suit your purpose even better. Listen to both your socket and System.in, and act on the one that provides input?

Comment: You cannot select on System.in.